# AngularJS swallowing HTML tags in textarea

Tags: angularjs

```
 <textarea id="Synopsis_Description" rows="9" class="form-control" ng-model="movie.summary" placeholder="Summary" ng-show="editMode"></textarea>
```

I'm entering the following data

```
I <u>am</u> in <strong>New York</strong>
```

But the controller is receiving only string

```
I am in New York
```

Any idea why this is happening

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kexcaliber/q6umxt8q/1/)

Comment: you say the controller not receive the html tags?, i just try in a proyect and works like : <textarea ng-model="tes" placeholder="Summary"></textarea>
            {{tes}}   that showing html tags, can you put a plunk or jsfiddle with problem?

Comment: Can you provide your controller code?

Comment: Please check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kexcaliber/q6umxt8q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

this is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/G9riRUm8HHmWccBO8K8a?p=preview

controller :

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.summary = null ;
      $scope.output = null ;
      $scope.updateMovie = function() {
        console.log($scope.summary);
         $scope.output = $scope.summary ;
      }
}
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <button ng-click="updateMovie()">Update</button><br>
   <textarea rows="9" class="form-control" ng-model="summary" placeholder="Summary" ></textarea>
   <br/>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-center" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="updateMovie()">Update</button>

    <span>{{output}}</span>

</div>
```

---

by default angular don't display html tag in the view to prevent code injection. you have to force it :

create a filter :

```
angular.module('filters', []).filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
   return function (val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
});
```

and use this in the view

```
<span ng-bind-html="varWithHtml | unsafe"></span>
```

Comment: Hi AlainIb I was able to  resolve the issue it was an issue with using $scope

Comment: great. if my answer help you you can accept it or if you have another solution you can create a new answer with your solution . It can help

Comment: Yes AlainIb I've created a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help the issue was with respect to using local variables in the controller instead of using $scope.movie.summary. This worked for me.

I used the following code to resolve it 
HTML Side:

```
<div class="genre-list">
   <div ng-hide="editMode">{{movie.summary}}</div>
   <textarea id="Synopsis_Description" ng-model="movie.summary" name="val_synopsis" placeholder="Summary" ng-show="editMode"></textarea>
   <button type="button" id="bold" ng-click="formatText('Synopsis_Description','strong')">Bold</button>
   <button type="button" id="italic"ng-click="formatText('Synopsis_Description','i')">Italic</button>
   <button type="button" id="underline" ng-click="formatText('Synopsis_Description','u')">Underline</button>
   <button type="button" id="linebreak" ng-click="formatText('Synopsis_Description','br')">Line-Break</button>
   <button type="button" id="hyperlink"  ng-click="formatUrl('Synopsis_Description');">Hyperlink</button>
</div>
```

AngularJS :

```
  /*Function for Editor*/
  $scope.formatText = function(text, tag) {
      var reg = new RegExp('<' + tag + '>');
      var newText;
      var obj = document.getElementById(text);
      var selectedText = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : obj.value.substring(obj.selectionStart, obj.selectionEnd);
      if (selectedText !== '') {
          if (reg.test(selectedText.replace(/<tag><\/tag>/g, ''))) {

              var re = new RegExp('<' + tag + '[><]*>|</' + tag + '[><]*>', 'g')
              newText = selectedText.replace(re, '');
              $scope.movie.summary = obj.value.replace(selectedText, newText);
              selectedText = '';
          } else {
              newText = $scope.movie.summary.substring(0, obj.selectionStart) + '<' + tag + '>' + $scope.movie.summary.substring(obj.selectionStart, obj.selectionEnd) + '</' + tag + '>' + $scope.movie.summary.substring(obj.selectionEnd);
              $scope.movie.summary = newText;
          }
      } else {
          alertify.error('Highlight the text to add required styles !!!');
          return false;
      }
      selectedText = '';
      obj.selectionStart = 0;
      obj.selectionEnd = 0;

  };


  /*Function for Additing Hyperlinks*/
  $scope.formatUrl = function(text) {
      var obj = document.getElementById(text);
      var urlname = '';
      var newText;
      var reg = new RegExp('a>');


      var selectedText = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : obj.value.substring(obj.selectionStart, obj.selectionEnd);

      if (selectedText !== '') {

          if (reg.test(obj.value.replace(/<[\/]{0}(a)[^><]*>/g, ''))) {
              var re = new RegExp('<a[^><]*>|<.a[^><]*>', 'g')
              newText = obj.value.replace(re, '');
              $scope.movie.summary = newText;
              selectedText = '';
          } else {
              urlname = prompt('Enter URL');
              newText = $scope.movie.summary.substring(0, obj.selectionStart) + '<a href="' + urlname + '" target="_blank">' + $scope.movie.summary.substring(obj.selectionStart, obj.selectionEnd) + '</a>' + $scope.movie.summary.substring(obj.selectionEnd);
              $scope.movie.summary = newText;
          }

      } else {
          alertify.error('Highlight the text to add required styles !!!');
          return false;
      }
      selectedText = '';
      obj.selectionStart = 0;
      obj.selectionEnd = 0;

  };
```